# Development to production updates using NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, version-control, development-environment, nosql

I've been using MongoDB for about a year now, however not nearly up to its potential.

I've been developing new software, out of anyone's eyes except my own, and I've enjoyed the flexibility of the database to its fullest and I've made major structural changes to data on the fly.

Now I'm at a point where I have production server(s) and 3 development servers, I'm having a real problem with changing data structures and syncing them up.

Theoretically the development servers should always have the most current data from production. In a structured database, if I rename something, I can just run a compare tool and do the corresponding change in production after a pull. In MongoDB, this can become incredibly difficult.. there could be hundreds of changes from document to document, much less from database to database.

I've been reviewing my `~/.dbshell` file to kinda get the feel of changes I've made, but what about changes made within the program its self? Configuration database changes?

Are there tools or procedures that are around to make this easier?

I've spent hours on Google researching how others do it. I came across Mongeez, but it's more manual and tedious than I need. In the past, I just do a `mongodump` and `mongorestore` inside of a git directory to transport data, but these snapshots are too rigid. I read a few blog posts regarding moving new data from production to development, but nothing about updating development documents in production. I could write a comparison script, but I feel like this is reinventing the wheel. There has to be a better way.

TL;DR: What are some ways to version NoSQL data, new entries and changed data, between environments?

Comment: do I understand this correctly: you want to lazily migrate your MongoDB documents from one data format to another? Why do you want to do this, i.e. why don't you run a script that migrates the entire database in one go like you would do with relational databases? (not that it wasn't possible, just trying to understand the why)

Comment: I want to _efficiently_ migrate documents regularly. After adding features in development, I want new data fields to be copied to the corresponding _id on production. I can't just dump dev into production because that'll remove new user posts and entries that may have occurred. I suppose I could write a script to check these incidences, but I'm just checking if there's anything else out there first.

Comment: Version docs. For each collection maintain code that can upgrade the doc to current version via a series of transformations. You could run it on demand and as a background worker to sweep through every document. Second, do design upfront so that this is minimized in the future.

Comment: I just keep the code for loading old formats of documents when necessary (it rarely is), but always safe them in the newest format. I basically treat old documents in the database the same way I treat old file formats. Maintain downward read compatibility but always write in the format of the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem/experience while managing a few production Mongo machines for about a year.

Two quick pieces of advice:

1. WiredPrairie is right. Version your documents and that will allow you to migrate in a casual/relaxed manner. I wish we had done that up front. One of my biggest regrets.
2. We used Groovy to connect and do our schema/data changes and I loved it. The language is easy to learn and it works great with JSON. My practice was to back up the collections I'd be operating on, write the scripts in dev, run them and if I messed up, restore the backed up collections. Iterate until I got the scripts perfect and then repeat in production.